# Обработка веб формы и возврат данных в виде заполненого PDF - шаблона

Tags: php, pdf, формы

Каким образом нужно обработать содержимое форм чтобы пользователю вернулся заполненный PDF документ

```
<form method="post" action="/handler.php">
    <div class="form-group"><label for="member_name">ФИО плательщика</label> 
    <input class="form-control" name="member_name" type="text" 
    placeholder="ФИО" 
    /></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="member_address">Адрес 
    плательщика</label> <input class="form-control" name="member_address" 
    type="text" placeholder="Адрес" /></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="payment_type">Выберите тип 
    квитанции</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="tally_type">
    <option value="newmans">Для вступающих в федерацию</option>
    <option value="members">Для членов Федерации</option>
    </select></div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" value="Скачать в 
    формате 
    PDF">
    <input type="hidden" name="cID" id="cID" value="155">
</form>
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/31438/ Класс FPDF для php

Comment: Насколько я знаю в FPDF и подобном все завязано на генерации нового документа, в моем же случае требуется заполнять уже имеющийся шаблон